# Interactive complete Brainfuck Interpreter

Tags: python, windows, interpreter, brainfuck

This is *another* Brainfuck interpreter in Python. I personaly think this is better than most of the other once you find online, because it keeps a `bracket_map`, which makes both `[` and `]` instant actions. The data array is a simple `defaultdict(int)`, so it is infinite is size in both directions (which  maybe a bad decision?) I am open to all critics and hope that somebody can tell if this is realy as efficient as I think.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from msvcrt import getch

program = "++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>."

def evaluate(sourcecode):
    bracket_map = {}
    stack = []
    for i, c in enumerate(sourcecode):
        if c == "[":
            stack.append(i)
        elif c == "]":
            s = stack.pop()
            bracket_map[s], bracket_map[i] = i, s
    assert not stack
    del stack
    data = defaultdict(int)
    data_index = 0
    program_index = 0
    while program_index < len(sourcecode):
        c = sourcecode[program_index]
        if c == "+":
            v = data[data_index] + 1
            if v > 255:
                v = 0
            data[data_index] = v
        elif c == "-":
            v = data[data_index] - 1
            if v < 0:
                v = 255
            data[data_index] = v
        elif c == ">":
            data_index += 1
        elif c == "<":
            data_index -= 1
        elif c == ".":
            print(chr(data[data_index]), end="")
        elif c == ",":
            data[data_index] = getch()[0]
        elif c == "[":
            if not data[data_index]:
                program_index = bracket_map[program_index]
        elif c == "]":
            if data[data_index]:
                program_index = bracket_map[program_index]
        program_index += 1


evaluate(program)
```

(if you are not on windows, you need an alternative for the `getch` function)

Answer (score 1):

All in all this looks good to me. I would make 2 changes

## `bracket_map`

The code to assemble this map can be more clear in it's own function.

## `+` and `-`

```
v = data[data_index] - 1
if v < 0:
    v = 255
data[data_index] = v
```

can be easily replaced by

```
data[data_index] = (data[data_index] - 1) % 256
```

Same goes for the `+` operation

Comment: I always forget about module of negative numbers.